# Vertical line with text in middle using html and css

Tags: html, css

I want to create like this

[image]

I am able to do like below

[image]

How to remove that excess line from starting

I am not able to post css and html code, giving some errors, so posting screenshots of code

[image]

[image]

Comment: why is that you are not able to post your code?

Comment: This is my first question in stackoverflow and i dont know it throwing some errors saying leave 4 spaces

Comment: Welcome to SO by the way. When you include the code, you need to format it by clicking on the { } to make it look like a code block. Try this way, please.

Answer (score 1):

I made this for you on JSFiddle, I hope it's what you're looking for.

```css
.timeline {
 position: relative;
 width: 30px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.timeline::after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 4px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.word {
 width: 100%;
 font: bold 12px arial, sans-serif;
 color: blue;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 background: #fff;
 overflow: hidden;
 z-index: 999;
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 auto 30px auto;
 padding: 5px 0;
 text-align: center;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
 <div class="word">2016</div>
 <div class="word">2014</div>
 <div class="word">2013</div>
 <div class="word">2012</div>
 <div class="word">2010</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Than you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
 <style>
    li{
        list-style: none;
       width: 50px;
       text-align: center;
    }
    li::before{
        content: ' ';
        position: relative;
        bottom: 2px;
        display: block;
        width: 5px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: red;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>2011</li>
        <li>2012</li>
        <li>2013</li>
        <li>2014</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This easily solved with [flex layout](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/). With flex layout it is much easier to layer out complex applications than with more classical block layout suggested in another answers.

You may take a look at flex and grid layouts with greatly helps with layering out modern apps.

```
.root {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   color: blue;
}

.line {
    height: 30px;
    width: 0px;
    border: solid
}    

<div class='root'>
    <div class='line'></div>
    <div class='text'>2016</div>
    <div class='line'></div>
    <div class='text'>2014</div>
    <div class='line'></div>
    <div class='text'>2012</div>
    <div class='line'></div>
    <div class='text'>2010</div>
    <div class='line'></div>
</div>
```

Here is the [sample](https://codepen.io/fyodor_e82/pen/LYYGQez?editors=1100)